# How does KVM virtual containers consume RAM?

Tags: ubuntu, kvm

I have a Physical server running with 47 GB of RAM and exact same Swap Space. The HDD space is 228GB .

I have launched 92 containers (KVM ones) and allocated 2560 MB of RAM to each container.

The current free memory status looks liks :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            47G         43G        263M         18M        3.0G        2.8G
Swap:           47G         17G         30G
```

The HDD storage:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             24G     0   24G   0% /dev
tmpfs           4.8G   23M  4.7G   1% /run
/dev/sda1       228G   33G  184G  15% /
tmpfs            24G     0   24G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            24G     0   24G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /run/user/1000
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

**Now my questions are:**

1. How do I determine the upper limit of maximum number of KVM
   containers that can be launched?
2. Do KVM also uses the available Swap space out of the system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's difficult to determine exactly how many containers you can run because you won't know until you've run them and they've started using RAM.  Linux only allocates RAM to a process when it actually uses it, not when it asks for it.  That's why you can run 235.5GB (92 x 2560MB) worth of VMs in only 47GB RAM + 47GB swap.
2. Yes.  VMs and containers are Linux processes like any other.  They can and will be swapped out when something else requires RAM.
3. I strongly recommend enabling zswap on your server, so that linux compresses swapped data, first in RAM and then (when that's getting full) in the swap partition on disk.  e.g.

```sh
# enable zswap
echo 1 > /sys/module/zswap/parameters/enabled

# set it to use lz4 (or use gzip for better compression but more CPU usage)
echo lz4 > /sys/module/zswap/parameters/compressor

# set maximum allowed percentage of RAM to use for swap
echo 50 > /sys/module/zswap/parameters/max_pool_percent
```

BTW, to see how much swap space is currently being used, run `swapon` with no arguments.  or run `top` or `htop`.